# CachedNetworkImageProvider error listener in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image

I want to use `CachedNetworkImageProvider` as the child of `Ink.image`. That is Ok to use. When I got the image with error path, how to use `errorListener` in `CachedNetworkImageProvider`. I want to show error icon instead of white blank container. please help. Below is my sample code that I want to use. I only want to use CachedNetworkImageProvider because of requirement.

```dart
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(9),
    ),
    child: Ink.image(
        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
            model.topAgentList[index].agent.profilePicture,
            errorListener: () {
                    
            },
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: InkWell(
            highlightColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => AgentProfileScreen(
                            agent: model.topAgentList[index].agent
                        )
                    )
                );
            },
        ),
    ),
),
```

What I expected is like that

[image]

..........

What I got is like that

[image]